# regex: match at least one character from set

Tags: regex, set, character, posix

I have a character set {x, y, z} and I want to check if some string contains at least one character from this set. 
For example:

```
abxyz - valid
zabc1 - valid
abc4e - not valid
```

Comment: Show us what you tried... Then we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
.*[x-z].*
```

This will only match lines that include `[x-z]` at least once.

**[Example](http://rubular.com/r/ugbaHtMrcc)**

Answer (score 3):

`/.*[xyz].*/` should do the trick

Comment: +1 for specifying set of discrete values rather than range. Range works for the given example, but the values in an arbitrary set may not be sequential.